# Why subcomponents in Angular should be registered via NgModule? What about encapsulation?

Tags: angular

I have some experience with other frameworks and architectural principles, and I absolutely don't understand the decision of Angular Team to deprecate the `directivies` property of a Component in RC6 in favor of `declarations` in NgModule.

Usually the architecture is about encapsulation, but suddenly if some functionallity of a component should be encapsulated by a child component, the subcomponent "leaks" up to the module, where it now should be registered.

1. So why by having a logical tree of components in a module, all of them should be registered "plain" inside NgModule?
2. Does this approach don't blow the ngmodule with a lot of imports and delcarations?

I understand that we can split everything into multiple modules, but inside a single module such global "load and register" remembers me to bunch of global `script [src]` tags  inside html.  I thought we have moved away from this pattern, but it looks like Angular returns to it.

It seems, I miss something here, could somebody please explain me?

---

[**EDIT 1**] (*breaks AOT compilation, see `edit-2`*)
Right now, we mimic nested components declaration, so that each component exports list of used components, and then in NgModule we go though all root components, collect their dependencies and prepair full `declarations` list.

It looks like this:

```
src/app    
    - /components/home-view/
        - /toolbar
            /menu-button
                - menu-button.component.ts

            - toolbar.component.ts

        - home-view.component.ts

    - app.module.ts
```

`app.module.ts`

```js
import { HomeViewComponent } from './components/home-view/home-view.component';

namespace Utils {
    export function flatternDirectives (arr: any[] = []): any[] {
        const declarations = arr.reduce((compos, compo) => {
            compos.push(...flatternDirectives(compo.directives), compo);
            return compos;
        }, []);
        return Array.from(new Set(declarations));
    }
}
@NgModule({
    declarations: Utils.flatternDirectives([
        HomeViewComponent,    
    ]),
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`./components/home-view/home-view.component.ts`

```js
import { ToolbarComponent } from './toolbar/toolbar.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home-view',
    template: `<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>`,    
})
export class HomeViewComponent {
    static directives = [ ToolbarComponent ]
}
```

`./components/home-view/toolbar/toolbar.component.ts`

```js
import { MenuButtonComponent } from './menu-button/menu-button.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-toolbar',
    template: `<app-menu-button></app-menu-button>`,    
})
export class ToolbarComponent {
    static directives = [ MenuButtonComponent ]
}
```

`./components/home-view/toolbar/menu-button/menu-button.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu-button',
    template: `<button></button>`,    
})
export class MenuButtonComponent {}
```

Are there any caveats in such approach?

---

[**EDIT 2**]
In DEV the approach above worked fine, but AOT compilation breaks with the error.

```
ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class 'name' in 'path'! Add 'name' to the NgModule to fix it.
```

So we must move back to plain declarations. Any solutions how tofix the aot compilation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

1. `NgModule` concept came late right before release, it provides standard way to create libraries/modules, adds effective import system and lazy loading feature. In many ways it similar to any other module/package system (i.e. declare module dependencies, module public exports etc.) with some limitations due to JS nature.
2. You can choose the granularity level when designing modules to avoid verbose imports/declarations. Libraries tend to use module per component strategy to minimize size impact (you import exactly what you need, no more), but sometimes you have to import many modules in this case.
3. The problem is that in AOT all component references must be resolved statically during compilation, you can not have dynamic code such as your `flatternDirectives` function since it is not statically analyzable. See https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#metadata-restrictions, I doubt that it is possible to write function that can remove duplicate entries, but probably you could use even duplicated entries i.e. `declarations: [HomeViewComponent.directives]` (need to check generated code).

Comment: Thank you, **1**.  Could you please specify what are the limitations? **2**.  What does it mean for application development: Assume I just started to impl. the app. I have a Root `NgModule`, then I add the `Toolbar` Component.  Afterwards I decide to add the `MenuButton` Component inside Toolbar.  The component is used only inside the `Toolbar` Component, do I have to create the NgModule for my toolbar? Further on, when `MenuButton` has a `ItemList` Component, do I have then create `NgModule` for `MenuButton`, and so on?

Comment: **3**. The problem could be resolved when it still would be the `directives` property in `@Component`. Then it is possilbe to aot to analize the components tree.  That is why I don't understand why the property was removed.

Comment: 1. You can browse angular api page for NgModule,  for example there is `declarations` field, angular can not automatically detect components that are used internally in the module, `entryComponents` must contain components that you want to create dynamically. This kind of registration usually is not needed in other UI frameworks. 2. If you don't want to create library or don't use lazy loading, then you should be fine with 1 module. If you want you can create any other module structure that fits your needs. 3. Probably, i guess it was compiler optimization.